# Broadcast Receiver in Phonegap 'Build'

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phonegap-build

I'm trying to receive a link shared from another application like browser or youtube into my `phonegap` app. I'm using `phonegap` build `(build.phonegap.com)` to make my app.

I'd like to know how to make my app appear in the 'share' list for links.

All solutions I found online are making me edit Android `Manifest` or `Java` files, but is there a way (a plugin of sorts) I can use to make data transfer between apps possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available for PhoneGap which will handle receiving content from other application. You can use it. Following is the link to this plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-intent

If you find any issue or something else other than that functionality, you can make the custom plugin so that you will have direct access of java file from javascript.

Comment: Thanks, but the suggested solution still wants me to edit the Android Manifest. Hence I was looking for a 'phonegap build' only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're talking about `deep linking` in android. The details about it can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)

Correct me if I explain your ideas wrong: What you want to do is that you have an URL that showed up in another application (Ex: Facebook Messenger, Slack, ...) and you want after clicking it, a list of application that can be used to open that link appear and you want your app to be listed there.

**But** here is the problem, *how can the OS knows what apps it can suggest to the end-user and what kind of link your is acceptable to your app?* the answer lies in your application `manifest` and to be more precise, the `intent-filter` tag. It tells the OS what you kind of url you want and also use it to determine if the OS should suggest your app to be open by using that link for the user.

So the answer for your question about doing without editing `Manifest` is impossible. As for the reason why you don't want to edit your apps is unknown to me but I still suggest you to take a look at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e). It still involves editing your `manifest` but the guide it self is clear and easy to implement.

Hope this help ^^

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a solution with Phonegap build.